# Start sidekiq automatically on OSX

Tags: ruby, rubygems, startup, sidekiq

I have coded up a small ruby gem that I use on my laptop to check disk space and other things.

I am using a sidekiq worker that runs periodically and emails me status updates.

I was wondering how to make a sidekiq worker run automatically after I restart OSX?  Is this possible?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run sidekiq you need to run: `bundle exec sidekiq`. If you want to run this on startup then you can follow these steps:

1. Start Automator.app;
2. Select "Application";
3. Click "Show library" in the toolbar (if hidden);
4. Add "Run shell script" (from the Actions/Utilities);
5. Add script '`bundle exec sidekiq` Or `cd YOUR_APP_PATH&&bundle exec sidekiq`;
6. Test it;
7. Save it somewhere: a file called your_name.app will be created);
8. Go to System Preferences → Accounts → Login items;

More startup script options [are here](https://superuser.com/questions/229773/run-command-on-startup-login-mac-os-x)

Comment: Got it! I just sourced my bash_profile before the call.

Answer (score 0):

Launch Redis on computer (Mac) starts.

```
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/redis/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
```

Edit `redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf`
and set `daemonize yes`

After you saved file with this change just start server:

```
src/redis-server
```