# How to run sidekiq in background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using this command

> bundle exec sidekiq -d

to run sidekiq server on the background. getting this error message

> ERROR: Daemonization mode was removed in Sidekiq 6.0, please use a proper process supervisor to start and manage your services.
>    sidekiq run but not in the background. After closing the console sidekiq automatically close.

Answer (score 1):

You need to open another terminal tab, in ubuntu <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and run command

```
 bundle exec sidekiq start
```

Comment: sidekiq run but after close instance console sidekiq automatically stop.

Comment: change gem version of sidekiq e.g gem 'sidekiq', '5.0.4' in gem file  and then bundle install as in greater version may be it has a bug.

Comment: same issue after change gem version

Comment: this is deprecated in newer versions. as mentioned in the question, the command is required for sidekiq gem version 6.0

Answer (score 1):

You may also think about using process manager like overmind which will help you manage multiple processes (for instance server and sidekiq) 
https://github.com/DarthSim/overmind

There are other tools around the web, this is my personal choice.

Comment: Thank you for an answer that isn't condescending garbage that assumes I'm using systemd or similar. Just to clarify, this is a good way to do it if you're using openrc?

Comment: You are welcome. Sadly, I've never used it in that scenario, so I'm only assuming there should be no problem at all. It just opens new tabs (sessions) and runs the given Procfile.

Answer (score 1):

It is removed from the latest versions of Sidekiq to promote users to learn the newer, better ways. Here is the link to the discussion on the same.

The discussion suggested using a process supervisor like systemd, upstart, foreman, etc. to manage Sidekiq.

So you need to write your own service file to start, stop sidekiq. For the reference, here is the link to example service of sidekiq.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/examples/systemd/sidekiq.service

Comment: in sidekiq.yml write this line
require 'sidekiq'
require 'sidekiq-status'
require 'sidekiq/web'

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.client_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add Sidekiq::Status::ClientMiddleware
  end
  config.redis = {:url => "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/5}" }
  config.failures_max_count = false
end

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the operating system so I'll just go with `ubuntu` production VM. You're going to want to setup sidekiq with something like `systemd` or `upstart`. Sidekiq has some example configurations to get you started https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/tree/master/examples.

I haven't done this on a mac before, but a quick google and found this [Start sidekiq automatically on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361783/start-sidekiq-automatically-on-osx).

Comment: sidekiq run but not continuously run. I have already used the same setup it's working but now it's stop I didn't get any solution for this

Comment: I am using ubuntu os

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will be very helpfull for someone

I start Sidekiq with '&' so it should move on to executing the next command, so Sidekiq runs in the background.

examples how I doing it

> to run sedekiq and redis-server in background

```
bundle exec sidekiq & redis-server --daemonize yes
```

> to run sedekiq in background and then rails server

```
bundle exec sidekiq & rails s
```